# How to call Java method in JavaFX menu

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. I created this simple menu.

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        // File menu - new, save, exit
        Menu menu = new Menu("File");
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save"));
        menu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));

        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        // Options menu - Preferences
        Menu options = new Menu("Options");
        options.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Preferences"));

        menuBar.getMenus().add(options);

        // Help menu - About
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");
        help.getItems().add(new MenuItem("About"));

        menuBar.getMenus().add(help);

        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Can you tell me how I can call Java method when I click on a menu? Just for a start I wan to call this Java method when I click `Exit`.

```
 public void programExit(){

       System.exit(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));` write:

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
```